# Simple JS calculator output issue

Tags: javascript

I have a calculator which I have put together to work out two values and then multiply by the third and simple out put the results.

I have created a demo but the issue I have is outputting the two id's `display` & `display2`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/bve0r078/#&togetherjs=cBMAdHvpOO)

```js
    function calculateCost() {

      var weeks = 52;
      var weeklyHours = 40;
      var display = document.getElementById("display");
      var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");

      // saves the value enterd in the annual salary field to a variable.
      var annualSalary = (document.getElementById("avgsalary")).value;
      // saves the value entered in the participants field to a variable
      var participants = (document.getElementById("numberrr")).value;
      //Divide the annual Salary by 52 to get the weekly salary figure.
      var weeklyWage = parseInt(annualSalary) / weeks;
      // Works out the CPH and saves the answer to a variable. 
      var costPerHour = weeklyWage / 40;

      // rounds the number up to nearest 2 decimal value.     
      costPerHour = Math.round(costPerHour * 100) / 100;

      /*console.log(costPerHour); */

      // saves the value entered into the hours field to a variable.
      var hours = (document.getElementById("hoursss")).value;

      // multiplies the CPH by the number of hours to give a figure for total cost per person.
      var costPerPerson = costPerHour * hours;


      // Multiplies the cost per person with the number of participants to give a figure for the total cost of the meeting. 
      var meetingCost = (costPerPerson * parseInt(participants));


      display.innerHTML = (costPerHour, meetingCost);

    }
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="money-ux">1. Average annual salary of participants
    <input class="avgsal" type="text" name="avgsalary" required id="avgsalary">
  </div>
  <div class="people-ux">2. Number of participants
    <input class="numpar" type="text" name="numberrr" required id="numberrr">
  </div>
  <div class="watch-ux">3. Duration of travel (hours)
    <input class="hour" type="text" name="hours" required id="hoursss">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="calc-btn" id="calculate" type="button" value="calculate" onclick="calculateCost();" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="reset-btn" id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
  </div>
</form>
<div id="display" style="height: 50px; border: thin solid red;"></div>
<div id="display2" style="height: 50px; border: thin solid green;"></div>
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: Where is the problem exactly ? I mean, at first look you got something in your `display` ; but I don't understand the meaning of `display2`

Comment: So there should be two outputs - one in the display ID and the other in display2 ID - display should output the costPerHour and display2 should output meetingCost

Comment: `display.innerHTML = (costPerHour, meetingCost);` mean put everything in `display` so I don't understand how you expect to find something in `display2` XD

Comment: @Blag sorry JS isn't my strongest skill however I understand what I have now done wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting two variables to elements on the page...

```
var display = document.getElementById("display");
var display2 = document.getElementById("display2");
```

... but you are only using one of them later to update values.

```
display.innerHTML = (costPerHour, meetingCost);
```

It looks like you simply need to use `display2` in the same fashion.

```
//for example
display.innerHTML = (costPerHour);
display2.innerHTML = (meetingCost);
```